# How do I decode content returned by JSON in a markdown style?

Tags: android, android-json, android-deep-link, android-json-rpc

I am using JSON to return a couple of objects, one of which is returned like this :

```
    "information": [{
    "title": "Wifi",
    "content": "__Network:__  WifiName \n__Password:__ abcde"
}, {
    "title": "Address",
    "content": "120 10th Ave\n San Francisco, CA 09601\n[Directions](https://goo.gl/maps/fzsXTCxw3Q5)"
}, {
    "title": "Help",
    "content": "Reach out to support if you have any trouble printing and we’ll be happy to help set you up."
}]
```

Now I don't have a clue how to decode the content in "content". Is there a way to decode this such that whatever markup is returned is recognized (including links if any are highlighted and clickable). I have no experience with this so kind of lost.

Any ideas? 
P.S: currently I get the content as is without any manipulation, I am wondering if there is any mechanism I can apply to recognize this returned markup
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by recognizing the markup? Do you want to display it in markup style?

Comment: Parse JSON to Object.?